# How to have IntelliSense list remaining field names when updating an object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

In Visual Studio, IntelliSense can really help you out when using the object initializer syntax by only popping up fields that you haven't yet set a value for.  For instance:

```
public class MyTestPerson
{
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

var newPerson = new MyTestPerson { Forename = "Joe", Surname = "Bloggs", | };
```

Assuming my cursor is where the "pipe" symbol is above, IntelliSense will only popup `Age` because it has recognized that I've already specified initializers for the other two fields.

Is there a way to get something similar to this for *updating* an object, though?  I want to make sure I set each of its fields once, and having this IntelliSense functionality would really help with that.  Obviously this will just popup all 3 fields:

```
var newPerson = new MyTestPerson();
newPerson.Forename = "Joe";
newPerson.Surname = "Bloggs";
newPerson.|
```

So is there a way I can just get it to popup the one field I've not yet updated, the `Age` field?  If not, is there a way I can use a lambda or maybe utilize the object initializer IntelliSense behaviour to update an object's fields "in one block", causing only the fields I haven't yet updated in that "block" to popup?

Comment: If you need to initialize all properties (not fields), then how about using constructor with parameters?

Comment: I think VS would need to be psychic when you've decided to stop setting properties on the object and are ready to call a method on it - everything up to the `.` will look exactly the same, but now you *don't* want the intellisense restricted down to just properties that you haven't set recently.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Which is why I ask whether there's some way to tell IntelliSense when you're setting properties on the object, other than when first initializing.  It would be really useful when updating a lot of stuff on an existing object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just gonna answer my question here: no.  There is no way to do this.  You can only popup "unset members" in IntelliSense when using the object initializer syntax.